# Auto login to jira on a raspberry pi wallboard

Tags: jira, chromium, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a raspberry pi wallboard to display the project jira status on a wall mounted screen. To make the raspberry pi work as a wallboard i have followed the tutorial on http://blogs.wcode.org/2013/09/howto-boot-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-fullscreen-browser-kiosk/. With some small changed i also managed to cycle it through several tabs using the command  `watch -n5 "xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+Tab"`

Now i want to display the jira status, on startup i need chromium to login and then display the status. I have tried this using the url `https://<company>.jira.com/login?username=<username>&password=<password>&dest-url=/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=<id>&view=detail`. But the jira login page does not seam to accept logins using the GET method.

Could someone help me to find a way to auto login to jira and then display some jira page? Of course this needs to be scripted on a raspberry pi 2 so the login is without user interaction at boot.

Answer (score 0):

You could look to boot up Chromium instead using like [Selenium Web Driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)  and have it navigate to the JIRA and perform your login using a read only service account on the required projects.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile i have found the answer. Jira simply accepts the parameters os_username and os_password or you can request a basic authentication challenge using os_authType=basic.

these URLs work

- `https://<company>.jira.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?os_username=<username>&os_password=<password>&rapidView=<id>&view=detail`
- `https://<username>:<password>@<company>.jira.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?os_authType=basic&rapidView=<id>&view=detail`

Comment: Scratch that, it was only the variant that uses a redirect from login page, that has stopped working. Supplying os_username and os_password directly to the desired page url works for Jira Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Jira Server 7.8 (not Jira Cloud), this works fine:

`https://your-jira.example.org/login.jsp?os_username=joe&os_password=secret&os_destination=/secure/Dashboard.jspa`

Customize `os_destination` as needed.

Source: [Receipe for wallboards in your office (Raspberry + Jira)](http://blog.macopedia.co/post/receipe-for-wallboards-in-your-office-raspberry-jira/)